# git warning - "You appear to have cloned an empty repository" - when cloning from github to local

Tags: github, warnings, git-clone

I got this unexpected warning message

```
~/work$ git clone git@github.com:user/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
```

when cloning from github to local.  The github repo was not empty.

Same for

```
~/work$ git clone git@github.com:user/myrepo.git
```

The new subdirectory `myrepo` was created, but calling `git status`, `git log`, `git history`, all showed empty results.

I have previously executed `git clone ...` and succeed in establishing clone subdirectories in this same `~/work` directory.

One possible (but not certain) difference is that all the files in `myrepo` were hand entered files.

The local directory `~/work` contained 43 subdirectories, but no files.

I created a new directory `~/github`.  Tried cloning from that directory and it worked fine:

```
~/github$ git clone git@github.com:user/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 118, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (118/118), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (109/109), done.
remote: Total 118 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (118/118), 25.71 KiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (55/55), done.
```

The work-around is achieved but the cause is unknown.

I though it best to leave this record for others.  I noticed many other postings containing "warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository", but most were due to having failed yo commit anything to the source repository.  So it is possible the circumstances in this report get lost in noise.

As a question - what is the cause?, and any similar experience?